# std::string and data alignment

Tags: c++, memory-alignment

I'm planning to use `std::string` as a generic data buffer (instead of roll my own). I need to pack all kinds of POD into it, including user defined structs, is the memory buffer allocated by `std::string` properly aligned for such purpose ?

If it's unspecified in C++ standard, what's the situation in libstdc++ ?

The host CPU is x86_64.

Comment: Why `std::string` instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: I don't care about the container as long as the memory buffer is aligned, is the buffer of std::vector guaranteed to be aligned?

Comment: BTW, data packed into the container have different size, I need interpret the buffer myself.

Comment: so, std::basic_string<long long> would probably satisfy the 16-byte alignment (required by x86_64 CPU), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `std::string` is probably not the best container to use if what you want to do is store arbitrary data. I'd suggest using `std::vector` instead.

Second, the alignment of all allocations made by the container is controlled by its allocator (the second template parameter, which defaults to `std::allocator<T>`). The default allocator will align allocations on the size of the largest standard type, which is often `long long` or `long double`, respectively 8 and 16 bytes on my machine, but the size of these types is not mandated by the standard.

If you want a specific alignment you should either check what your compiler aligns on, or ask for alignment explicitly, by supplying your own allocator or using `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the allocator will be used to make any allocations needed by the container... so that implies the std::basic_string's data() will lie *somewhere* within some chunk of memory allocated by the allocator.  But are you sure it's guaranteed to be at the *beginning* of a chunk of memory allocated by the allocator?   I can imagine some implementation might position the basic_string's data() 4 or 8 or 12 bytes past the beginning, for example.

Comment: I don't see any guarantee that data() points to the *beginning* of an allocated block of memory, in my reading of section 24.3.2.7.1.  Are you sure you're citing the right section?   (BTW the link you gave points to what looks to me like a moving target; for reference it's currently Strings library / String classes / Class template basic_­string / String operations / Accessors, in some draft of some version of the c++ spec.)

Comment: Not sure whether my emphasis is getting communicated.  I've been emphasizing the word "beginning", since that's now the crux of the issue.

Comment: What do you mean "aligned as requested"?  This question is about whether basic_string's data() has any alignment guarantees.  No alignment requests are ever made on that, as far as I can see.

Comment: My reading of your sentence "The default allocator will align allocations on the size of the largest standard type, which is often long long or long double, respectively 8 and 16 bytes on my machine, but the size of these types is not mandated by the standard."  is that you are meaning to imply that data() has that same alignment guarantee.   If you are not meaning to say that, than maybe an edit for clarity would be helpful.

Comment: Oh?  Okay, then, again: your conclusion (that data() has the same alignment guarantees as the default allocator) does not follow from anything you've cited or said, as far as I can see.